# How to set multiple keyframes to run respectively after each other for infinite times

Tags: css, loops, animation, sag

I have an svg container div containing multiple svg text to set the first text to fadeout and the second text to fadein in its place using css keyframes. I was wondering if there is anyway to set the entire animation to play infinity?

```
<html>
<div id="fading">
<svg>
 <text class="fadingA" x="20%" y="50%">Follow Me</text> 
 <text class="fadingB" x="13%" y="50%">On Social Media</text>
 </svg>
```

```
.fadingA{
font-size: 100px; fill:#BFAE99;
stroke: #171F26; stroke-width:3px;
stroke-dasharray: 352.6px;
animation: animate1 3s ease forwards;
}
.fadingB{
 font-size: 100px; fill: transparent;
 stroke: #171F26; stroke-width:3px;
 stroke-dasharray: 457.7px;
 stroke-dashoffset: 457.7px;
 animation: animate2 3s ease forwards;
 animation-delay: 3s;
 }

 @keyframes animate1{

 to{
  stroke-dashoffset: 352.6px;
  fill: transparent;
 }
 }
 @keyframes animate2 {
 to{
 stroke-dashoffset:0px;
 fill:#BFAE99;
 }
 }
```

Comment: problem solved thank you.